# two sites, same code, different presentation

Tags: php, virtual-hosts

I have created two web sites. One is "production" and the other "dev". Each is a virtual host and both are on a single server running apache. Both sites are loaded with the same code base: WP 3.5.1, a base theme and a child theme. This is not a multi-site setup; just two sites loaded in different directories.

The page in question uses a page template. In the page template there is some switching in PHP code to choose what to display. The switching is based on the $current_user->ID. If ID is null or zero display a logon block otherwise look up some data to present.

This works fine on the dev site. It does not work on the production site. Something is different. I checked .htaccess, the virtual host declaration in apache, and the settings for WP and the theme. They all appear to be the same. I have run delta checks on the code and the two sets of files are identical.

What other config settings might be in play here?

Comment: Is the production database a clone of the dev database? Also, it might be helpful if you posted the code that is not working.

Comment: Yes, the dev database is a clone of the production site, new code was pushed from dev to prod. Happy to do so, but it is long so I will set up a link to the code.

Comment: Here is the code snippet. It is long because I am not convinced the problem is in the code, but open to new info so err on the side verbosity. http://pastebin.com/hF2VCPLv

Comment: I doubled checked the php info. Except for the urls and hash codes, the two sites report the same details.

Comment: Hmmm, the only possible hiccup I see is that if the user ID is NULL for any reason the first part of the IF statement fails. `if ( isset($current_user->ID) && $current_user->ID == 0 )`

Comment: Ah, good eye. I will check that. Also, I notice that firePHP headers are not received by the browser on the site having trouble. The headers are received from the other site. What might cause that?

Comment: One more clue: I notice that html comments I placed in the page template do not appear in the problem site, but do in the dev site. Paths are correct.

Comment: I just noticed that your template name is not fully commented `<?php Template Name: xxx */`. Perhaps the missing `/*` is causing issues?

Comment: Many thanks to @epilektric for making suggestions. I will check the comment closures. However, PBKAC: the page template was not assigned to the target page in the prod site. Such a dumb error; one I thought I checked. I will now slither off to a dark corner and reprimand myself.

Comment: Lol! We've all made those mistakes. No worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After walking through the code and examining everything else, I (finally) revisited the page definition in the Dashboard. There I noticed that the page was not associated with the page template I was working with. I assume that during the migration from the development web site to the production web site, the association went missing.

FTR, "PBKAC" stands for **p**roblem **b**etween **k**eyboard **a**nd **c**hair.